# Importing TIF raster in QGIS, default color band

Tags: qgis, raster, color, geotiff-tiff, band

Where can I change the default color bands for importing raster images?

When I import a TIF image the green color band is not set causing a purplish image.

When I set it in the properties it views correctly, but I have a lot of images to import and would like it set by default.

A week ago I was not having this problem, but I can't find how to set it back.

Answer (score 2):

In `Settings -> Options, rendering tab` you can select the default settings for the three bands used for RGB rendering. It should be set to `1-2-3`.

It might be that some exotic Raster files have stored a different color scheme inside.